# Since I'm blind and Visual Studio isn't accessible, can I create C# WPF applications just with plain code?

Tags: c#, wpf, accessibility

I am totally blind, I use NVDA screen reader to operate my system, and I am trying to create a Windows desktop application. Visual Studio isn't screen-reader friendly, at least not the forms designer part. VS Code is pretty much accessible, although powershell's protools' designer isn't.

Whenever I see a question about writing GUI in WPF with pure code I find a lot of "why in the name of God would you want to do that? Use VS!" answers. Well, here is the reason, VS form designer is out of reach to blind programmers, so the least practical approach will have to do.

So, can it be done? Would you suggest any resources or approaches to this?

Comment: A lot of the time, us backend programmers who also dabble in frontend WPF, prefer editing the XAML directly anyway. Occasionally, because WPF is so configurable (think CSS, with much less intuitive syntax), one sometimes need a visual on how something would look when their style is changed. But as long as you stick with standard stuff, I believe it should be completely fine.

Comment: Hm, why are you saying VS is not accessible? I have no idea about NVDA though, but I myself sometimes work with it and I know several people who use it every day with JAWS. Try installing at least a demo version, maybe it's worth investing in JAWS to do your job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to try and build up from the other example to get you compile-able code. To get WPF working, you'll need a project that builds with WPF support.

The simplest way is to create a `.csproj` ourself and use the previously posted code-only solution.

So, start with a minimal `App.csproj` file as so:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Then the app & window code in `App.cs` as before. I've added a couple controls to it, as you'll need a container anyway (I used `StackPanel`) if you want to start adding more stuff later.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

public class App : Application {
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)     {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        new MainWindow().Show();
    }

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main() => new App().Run();
}

public class MainWindow : Window {
    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnInitialized(e);

        var panel = new StackPanel();
        this.Content = panel;

        var label = new Label { Content = "Click me:" };
        panel.Children.Add(label);
        
        var closeButton = new Button { Content = "Close", Height = 100 };
        closeButton.Click += (sender, args) => this.Close();
        panel.Children.Add(closeButton);

        (this.Width, this.Height) = (200, 200);
    }
}
```

You then build the whole project by using `dotnet build`. And you can run it with `dotnet run` or invoking the exe directly.

Alternatively, if you'd like to explore a WPF project with separate .xaml and .xaml.cs code, you can create your project using `dotnet new wpf -o MyProjectName`. This will produce a project, a xaml-based App, and a xaml-based form.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You can do WPF only with code.

Here is a simple example from http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0470__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/CodeOnlyWPFApplicationSample.htm

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

  public class App : Application {

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) {
      base.OnStartup(e);
      MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
      window.Show();
    }

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.Run();
    }
  }

  public class MainWindow : Window {

    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e) {
      base.OnInitialized(e);
      Button closeButton = new Button();
      closeButton.Content = "Close";
      this.Content = closeButton;
      closeButton.Click += delegate {
        this.Close();
      };
    }
  }
```

Also, it might be easier to use WinForms since it uses C# as code-behind and less XML.

Comment: And how can I build this into a test executable? I pasted this code into a program.cs file and tried csc program.cs, but it returned an error saying some using statement about OnStartup.